# huawei App Signing Export and upload key and certificate

Tags: android, huawei-developers, android-app-signing, app-signing

I would like to upload my app to the Huawei App Gallery. I am stuck at the App Signing process.

To perform App Signing, you will need to choose one of 2 options:

1. Let AppGallery Connect create and manage app signature for you (recommended and applicable only to new app release)
2. Export and upload key and certificate

Unfortunately, the instructions in Huawei App Gallery tells you to `Obtain the pepk.jar file from the Internet or another legitimate source.` but do not provide a link from which the PEPK Tool (pepk.jar) can be downloaded.

Where can I find the "legal channels" to download the tool?

**EDIT: Huawei App Gallery Instructions for reference**

1. Obtain the pepk.jar file through the Internet or other legal channels.
2. Run the following command to export and encrypt your private key and public key certificate into a ZIP file. Parameters in bold must be replaced as needed. Then, enter your storage location and key password as prompted.

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore test.jks --alias test --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=<some-encryption-key> --include-cert
```

3. Upload the ZIP file containing the private key and public key certificate. (The ZIP file contains only certificate.pem and encryptedPrivateKey.)

**SECOND EDIT: Google Play PEPK**
When opting in for Google Play App Signing they provide a link to:
[PEPK tool](https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar) and [PEPK tool source code](https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk-src.jar).

**EDIT FOR REOPENING**
This is a serious question. The Huawei app gallery tells you to find the pepk.jar file from somewhere. A file which should handle your signing certificates so it's pretty important this one is not tampered with. So this question is not opinion based, but rather the question is, where can we get the official pepk.jar from google.

Comment: I found it in Android Studio files at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\pepk.jar`

Comment: I was able to download the `pepk .jar` from google itself. It can be found [here](https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar)

Comment: Can you provide a URL that does not directly start downloading a file. As far as I know I might be downloading some malware named pepk.jar.

Comment: You can copy the link location and check it in the text file. But here is the breakdown.
Full URL: https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar
If you remove the last part, you will find the google 404.
You can also use a DNS who is to verify that this is a Google-owned domain and legit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

•  Usually, the pepk.jar file is located under the next structure directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\
```

but you have to use the pepk.jar from Google:

https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar

• Use double quotes to indicate paths.

Example to create the .zip file required for Huawei App Gallery:

> java **-jar** "C:\Program Files\Android\Android
> Studio\plugins\android\lib\pepk.jar" **--keystore**
> "C:\Data\Jorgesys_Android\KEYSTORE\gruporeformakey.jks" **--alias**
> jorgeysioana
> **--output**="C:\Data\Jorgeys_Android\KEYSTORE\app_gallery_cert.zip" **--encryptionkey**=012300045E224EE22B45D19B23DB91BA9F52DE0A06513E03A5821409B34976FDEED6E0A47DBA48CC249DD93734A6C5D9A0F43461F9E140F278A5D2860846C2CF5D12345 **--include-cert**

Then you get as a result the .zip in the output path (--output).

Comment: Hi @Jorgesys, what is encryptionkey in command and how to generate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from here
https://github.com/yongjhih/pepk

At the bottom of the readme.md

Comment: I also stumbled upon that repo. I am still not sure if that is the 'official' pepk tool.

Comment: It has 2 start ... i think no

Answer (score 0):

Just change the pepk.jar file and get the file from a trusted place
As reported by the official website

[https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-faq-0000001052944432#:~:text=The%20output.zip,a%20signature%20file](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-faq-0000001052944432#:%7E:text=The%20output.zip,a%20signature%20file).